# Center button background - Xamarin c#

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I have a button

```
Android.Widget.Button btnDelTR = new Android.Widget.Button(this);
btnDelTR.SetBackgroundResource(Resource.Drawable.delete);
```

i want to change it backgroung it works fine,
but the background size is **Stretch**
and simply i **want to center the background image**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe easier if you use an imagebutton:

https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/controls/imagebutton/create_an_imagebutton/

You can use the parameters of an image as well to adjust the background.

Comment: Thank you what i want i just to adjust yhe background or the image to the center of the button

Comment: In LinearLayout, use: android:layout_gravity="center".

In RelativeLayout, use: android:layout_centerInParent="true"

Comment: the button is inside a TableRow and im adding button without Text and with an image Background to each row,